# TortoiseGit how to edit or remove some files locally without affecting the online repository

Tags: git, repository, tortoisegit

I basically clone a Git repository locally with TortoiseGit and which contains for exemple 2 files:
- header.php
- index.php

I would like to remove or edit header.php and also edit index.php, but when I commit & push I want only the changes on index.php update the online repository (which will contain the unchanged header.php and the new index.php modified)

and I do not want to change .gitignore ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right click in your repository and click `Git commit -> "master"`.

[image: Step 1]

2. Uncheck `header.php` in the `Changes made` area. Enter a commit message and click `OK`.

[image: Step 2]

3. On the progress dialog that pops up, click `Push...` to push your changes to the remote repository.

[image: Step 3]

4. On the push dialog that pops up, click `OK`.

[image]

Your changes to `index.php` will now be pushed to the remote repository, and your changes to `header.php` will still be present on disk.